# Adding content via CSS with data attribute

Tags: html, css, attributes, media-queries

I would like to append dates to the end of several strings of text with screens smaller that 500px.

My HTML is:

```
      <div class="left-section" id="activities">
      <ul>
        <li data-string="September 2012 - May 2014">National Student Advertising Competition</li>
        <li data-string="January 2012 - May 2014">Advertising Club</li>
        <li data-string="November 2012 - May 2013">Interactive Marketing Association | Student Board Member</li>
        <li data-string="September 2011 - May 2014">University Intramural Co-Ed Volleyball and Soccer</li>
      </ul>  
      </div>
```

And my CSS in the media query is:

```
  #activities:after {
  content: " - " attr(data-string);
}
```

All that displays are the strings and then after the list is the " - "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space and `*` before the `:after` to get everything inside `#activities` like this:

```css
  #activities *:after {
  content: " - " attr(data-string);
}
```

```html
      <div class="left-section" id="activities">
      <ul>
        <li data-string="September 2012 - May 2014">National Student Advertising Competition</li>
        <li data-string="January 2012 - May 2014">Advertising Club</li>
        <li data-string="November 2012 - May 2013">Interactive Marketing Association | Student Board Member</li>
        <li data-string="September 2011 - May 2014">University Intramural Co-Ed Volleyball and Soccer</li>
      </ul>  
      </div>
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks for your response! The " - " at the bottom is gone so I can assume the code is valid but I must have something wrong still because it's not working. Here's my site https://radmint.github.io/

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: OK, I got it: There are two problems that I found: 1) In your media queries in your stylesheet, you used "max-device-width" which doesn't seem to work. However, "max-width" does work, so use that. 2) You didn't use my code correctly. You wrote: "#activities: *after" when you should have written "#activities *:after". Fix that, and it should work. I edited your code in dev tools and it worked as you would want it to work.

Comment: I fixed the activities *:after issue I had and then it worked. For some reason if I take 'device' out of 'max-device-width' none of my media queries work. I'm not sure if that's normal. I've been developing in Chrome. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm on Chrome. For me, max-width works. I don't know why it doesn't work on your device.